# How to retrieve data child in a child from firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Android and Firebase. 
I would like to gain exposure and learn these two technologies with a project. 
Here is my problem.
I changed the structure of a database in Firebase and I don't know how to retrieve the data again.

Here is the structure before:

[image]

And

After:

[image]

This is my code to retrieve data before:

```java
     mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
     mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

    //OnStart 
     FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>
                (Blog.class, R.layout.blog_row, BlogViewHolder.class, mDatabase) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final BlogViewHolder viewHolder, final Blog model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getId());
                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
                final View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.blog_row, null);
                viewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Join_activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
```

I have tried the code from here and other platform and I don't get the answer. Please help me.

Comment: By the way, how to show the image without link? I'm new here. Sorry if this is a bad post.

Comment: May I ask why you changed the structure to have 1,2 inside Events? I do not think that is a good design, if you need to get the position of those items you can get them from the populatevViewModel() method.

Comment: I want to try the other structure sir.
Can you help me? @NoelOmondi

Answer (score 0):

The 1 and 2 parents of Expo and training should be push keys instead of static numbers.

To show the image you should use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)

The problem retrieving your database data is at this line

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events");
```

inside your `populateViewHolder` when you do this

```
viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
```

or trying to request any data, it won't be at your reference `.child("Events")`, instead you should replace your reference with something static or do a for loop to get all the nodes

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Events").child("1").child("Expo");
```

Comment: Okay, i will try to change that "1,2" into push keys.
I understand sir. But i tried the most bottom code, it gives me error

Comment: For the image, i have done that thanks sir. It works

Comment: Do you mean for the loop i need to use mDatabase.addValueEventListener?
Sorry for too much asks. I'm really curious for this.